# How to verify a jQuery plugin is compatible with latest version of jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Are there any tools that can verify whether a jQuery plugin will be compatible with the latest version of jQuery?

Once a large number of jQuery plugins are selected and in use, an unknown number of dependencies can develop.  It would be nice to upgrade jQuery, however not all plugins remain supported or provide consistently architected upgrades.

The only option seems to be adhoc manual regression testing.  It would be nice to have a strategy for dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use that plugin with new jquery library

Comment: This does not take into account the numerous configuration options of some plugins which may work under one configuration but not another.  It doesn't consider the complexity of testing the large number of plugins that gradually work their way into an app, and it does not respect the question. I will wait a few days to see if a serious answer is provided.  If nothing appears, I will accept this answer which basically implies that random adhoc testing is indeed the only option at this point.